# How to validate if a string is a valid date or not in Lua?

Tags: validation, date, lua

s = "2/29/2010"

how to validate the above string is a valid date in Lua?

Comment: By "valid", I assume that you mean "is it a valid date in the only country on the planet that uses the retarded format of mm/dd/yyyy when writing dates instead of either the logical progression dd/mm/yyyy or the iso standard yyyy/mm/dd"

Comment: I thought there could be a standard library function in Lua for validating if the date is a valid one from the string representation. For example, Feb 29, 2010 is a valid date or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such thing in the standard Lua library, but can be easily created yourself:

```
function is_valid_date(str)

  -- perhaps some sanity checks to see if `str` really is a date

  local m, d, y = str:match("(%d+)/(%d+)/(%d+)")

  m, d, y = tonumber(m), tonumber(d), tonumber(y)

  if d < 0 or d > 31 or m < 0 or m > 12 or y < 0 then
    -- Cases that don't make sense
    return false
  elseif m == 4 or m == 6 or m == 9 or m == 11 then 
    -- Apr, Jun, Sep, Nov can have at most 30 days
    return d <= 30
  elseif m == 2 then
    -- Feb
    if y%400 == 0 or (y%100 ~= 0 and y%4 == 0) then
      -- if leap year, days can be at most 29
      return d <= 29
    else
      -- else 28 days is the max
      return d <= 28
    end
  else 
    -- all other months can have at most 31 days
    return d <= 31
  end

end
```

*(untested!)*

Or do a search for ["lua date parsing"](https://www.google.com/search?q=lua+date+parsing) to find a 3<sup>rd</sup> party library that will do this for you.

Comment: fyi "else" is redundant after a return. ie `if (x) then return y else return z end` can be simplified to `if (x) then return y end return z`. Applies to all languages. It's one of my pet hates btw. +1 for effort though :)

Answer (score 4):

```
function checkDate(us_mdY) 
    local m, d, Y = us_mdY:match("(%d+)/(%d+)/(%d+)")
    local epoch = os.time{year=Y, month=m, day=d}
    local zeromdy = string.format("%02d/%02d/%04d", m, d, Y)
    return zeromdy == os.date('%m/%d/%Y', epoch)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function isdate(value)
    --  Check for a UK date pattern dd/mm/yyyy , dd-mm-yyyy, dd.mm.yyyy
    --      My applications needs a textual response
    --      change the return values if you need true / false
    if (string.match(value, "^%d+%p%d+%p%d%d%d%d$")) then
        local d, m, y = string.match(value, "(%d+)%p(%d+)%p(%d+)")
        d, m, y = tonumber(d), tonumber(m), tonumber(y)

        local dm2 = d*m*m
        if  d>31 or m>12 or dm2==0 or dm2==116 or dm2==120 or dm2==124 or dm2==496 or dm2==1116 or dm2==2511 or dm2==3751 then
            -- invalid unless leap year
            if dm2==116 and (y%400 == 0 or (y%100 ~= 0 and y%4 == 0)) then
                return "valid"
            else
                return "invalid"
            end
        else
            return "valid"
        end
    else
        return "invalid"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

While Bart Kier's response is logically organized, presented and clear, it allows nonsense dates with zero values such as '00/12/2011' and '02/00/2012' to pass validation. I've corrected it below by changing the '<' checks for month, day and year to '<='.

```
function is_valid_date(str)

  -- perhaps some sanity checks to see if `str` really is a date

  local m, d, y = str:match("(%d+)/(%d+)/(%d+)")

  m, d, y = tonumber(m), tonumber(d), tonumber(y)

  if d <= 0 or d > 31 or m <= 0 or m > 12 or y <= 0 then
    -- Cases that don't make sense
    return false
  elseif m == 4 or m == 6 or m == 9 or m == 11 then 
    -- Apr, Jun, Sep, Nov can have at most 30 days
    return d <= 30
  elseif m == 2 then
    -- Feb
    if y%400 == 0 or (y%100 ~= 0 and y%4 == 0) then
      -- if leap year, days can be at most 29
      return d <= 29
    else
      -- else 28 days is the max
      return d <= 28
    end
  else 
    -- all other months can have at most 31 days
    return d <= 31
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Jeff Drumm and Bart Kier don't take into account that the string could be something that is not a date at all. I added the code to return false in case the year/month/date is not found to Jeff Drumms answer in the code below.

```
function IsValidDate(str)
  -- perhaps some sanity checks to see if `str` really is a date
  local y, m, d = str:match("(%d+)/(%d+)/(%d+)")
  if y == nil or m == nil or d == nil
  then
    return false
  end
  m, d, y = tonumber(m), tonumber(d), tonumber(y)

  if d <= 0 or d > 31 or m <= 0 or m > 12 or y <= 0 then
    -- Cases that don't make sense
    return false
  elseif m == 4 or m == 6 or m == 9 or m == 11 then 
    -- Apr, Jun, Sep, Nov can have at most 30 days
    return d <= 30
  elseif m == 2 then
    -- Feb
    if y%400 == 0 or (y%100 ~= 0 and y%4 == 0) then
      -- if leap year, days can be at most 29
      return d <= 29
    else
      -- else 28 days is the max
      return d <= 28
    end
  else 
    -- all other months can have at most 31 days
    return d <= 31
  end
end
```